# How to get the position of the point in the view after rotate?

Tags: java, android, math, coordinates

I have a `View` that has the moving, rotating and scaling capability, I have all the four-corner positions and I want to get the position of some imaginary points in it so that can be constant with scaling and moving
Please take a look at the picture below to understand it well.

[image]

Comment: please refer this link it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583220/android-get-new-coordinates-after-rotation?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

After re-reading I see that question is not clear

If you need to transform points when you know initial and ending corner coordinates, then calculate matrix of affine transform using three pairs of coordinates as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/transfer-coordinates-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle/18848074#18848074) and apply that matrix to all needed points.

But you also mentioned `points .. that can be constant` - as far as I understand - point that preserve their coordinates after transform.

You should know matrix of affine transform that is applied to your coordinates.

For this matrix calculate [eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) (there are up to three of them)

If some eigenvalue is 1, then static point does exist, and corresponding eigenvector being normalized to the form `(x,y,1)` represents coordinates of your static point.